# Нормализация данных с помощью методов

Tags: python, pandas

В задании написано что надо Провести нормализацию данных и перечислены вот эти методы:

```
MinMaxScaler;
MaxAbsScaler;
RobustScaler;
StandardScaler
```

Подскажите что в пределах этих двух датасетов надо нормализовать и как?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему не следует так делать, чем плохи скриншоты (картинки). https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 2):

Все указанные в вопросе скейлеры работают сугубо с числами с плавающей точкой. Поэтому нормализовывать ими нужно числовые колонки. Если же посмотреть на второй датасет, то там есть колонки, у которых явно всего два значение - `0.0` и `1.0`, это явно просто какие-то бинарные признаки, их скейлить бессмысленно. Ну то есть вы можете их скейлить, и в результате они скорее всего просто никак не поменяются, но это пустая работа.

Как именно применять эти методы прекрасно описано в документации к `scikit-learn`, там и примеры есть. Вот, например, [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Хотя там могут быть ещё тонкости, ладно, вот вам пример применения на тех же ирисах:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = iris['data']
sns.scatterplot(x = df.index, y = df['sepal length (cm)']);
plt.title('Не нормализованные данные');
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_norm = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(x = df_norm.index, y = df_norm['sepal length (cm)']);
plt.title('Нормализованные данные');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, данные остаются те же самые, но смещаются так, что среднее у них теперь `0`, а стандартное отклонение должно быть `1`, в этом суть работы `StandardScaler`.

Кстати, проверим это:

```
import numpy as np

for col in df_norm.columns:
    print(f'{col}: {np.mean(df_norm[col]):.4f}, {np.std(df_norm[col]):.4f}')
```

Ну, с определённой точностью (расхождения там где-то в 16-м знаке, если напечатать числа целиком), так и есть:

```
sepal length (cm): -0.0000, 1.0000
sepal width (cm): -0.0000, 1.0000
petal length (cm): -0.0000, 1.0000
petal width (cm): -0.0000, 1.0000
```

Comment: во втором датасете я в одном задании уже просто нормализировал данные когда заполнял пропущенные значения(в гайде я смотрел так делали)  через MinMaxScaler и я датасет уже с измененными колонками получил. Так что не знаю может в этом задании надо загрузить по новой этот датасет которым он был изначально

Comment: @Максим Да, на картинке у вас явно уже нормализованные каким-то скейлером значения. Так то в принципе можете брать и уже обработанный датасет, разницы думаю на выходе не будет. Но вообще по-нормальному надо брать, конечно, исходный датасет каждый раз.

Comment: Там вообще еще сказано провести проверку полученных после нормализации даных это интересно что значит

Comment: Ну наверное как-раз что-то типа того, что я делаю в конце ответа. Кстати, кажется numpy может и не нужен, у pandas кажется свои методы для этого есть

Comment: Ну вот я там смотрю у вас на фото все на диаграмме рассеивания осталось одинаково но при этом поменялся диапазон значений на оси y. Какой вывод можно к этому результату написать?

Comment: Так я ж не знаю, что от вас требуют. Я всё в ответе написал, что об этом думаю.